# sapui5 application is not open inside portal iView in IE11 default browser mode 5

Tags: iframe, sapui5, internet-explorer-11, portal

I created an application using sapui5.I am using sapui5 library 1.40 in server NW7.4 sp6. This application working fine in chrome.

If I open this application in new Tab of IE11. It's working fine but when I am trying to call inside Portal iView. sapui5 library is not loaded, due to this my application is giving error "sap is undefined".

Please find attached document of screenshots for the reference. I have attached console log of the browser as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are the "attached document of screenshots for the reference"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. [SAPUI5 dropped support for IE11](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933). The question is incomplete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Portal isn't able to run SAPUI5 iView that don't run with the standards mode. SAP provides a lot of documentation through SAP note and SDN blogs about that but the one that could help you the most might be the following:
https://blogs.sap.com/2014/09/03/ie-and-portal-standardsquirks-mode-evolution-or-love-hate-relationships/

To sum it up, your SAPUI5 iView must run with NavMode 10 ("Standard headerless framework page"), this should enable edge document mode, be careful that the entreprise mode for IE11 is not activated otherwise edge mode won't be usable.

Hope this will help you.